# Internal server error 500 in backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, resteasy

while saving form details using backbone i m getting error as

```
POST http://localhost:8080/gamingengine/restful-services/badges 500 (Internal Server Error)
st.ajaxTransport.sendjquery.js:4
st.extend.ajaxjquery.js:4
Backbone.ajaxbackbone.js:1197
Backbone.syncbackbone.js:1178
_.extend.syncbackbone.js:284
_.extend.savebackbone.js:490
Backbone.Form.extend.saveBadgesbadges.js:219
st.event.dispatchjquery.js:3
st.event.add.y.handle

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
st.extend.parseJSONjquery.js:2
window.clearErrorscommon.js:386
st.event.dispatchjquery.js:3
st.event.add.y.handlejquery.js:3
st.event.triggerjquery.js:3
rjquery.js:4
st.ajaxTransport.send.r
```

my backbone code is as follows

```
this.model.save(this.getValue(), {
    //beforeSend : setHeader,         //added
    iframe : true,
    wait : true,
    files : $file,
    elem : this,                        
    data : _.omit(this.getValue(), ['iconFile']),
    silent : true,
    success : function(model, response, options) {
        alert("inside save..");
        var error = false;
        _.each(response, function(val, key) {
                if (app.BadgesView.fields[key]
                    && val instanceof Object
                        && val.error) {
        
                    error = true;
                    app.BadgesView.fields[key]
                            .setError(val.message);

                }
            });
            
                   if (!error) {
               app.BadgesView.model.set(model);
               app.BadgesListCollection.add(model);
               return;

            }
            return false;
        },
        error : function(model, response, options) {
            console.log("error while save in badges.js : ");
            }
        });
```

and server side code is as follows which is using resteasy

```
@POST
    @Consumes("multipart/form-data")
    @Produces("text/html")
    @Cache(noStore = true)
    public final Response saveBadges(
        @MultipartForm final BadgesForm badgesForm) throws IOException {

        System.out.println("saveBadges called........");
        final int no_of_coins = badgesForm.getNo_of_coins();
        final String badge_name = badgesForm.getBadge_name();
        final int score = badgesForm.getScore();
        final int badge_id = badgesForm.getBadge_id();

        final byte[] iconFile = badgesForm.getIconFile();

        final Validator validatorNumeric = ValidationFactory
                .getTextFieldNumericValidator();

        validatorNumeric.validate("no_of_coins", no_of_coins,
                threadlocalExceptions.get());

        System.out.println("iconFile :" + iconFile);

        if (iconFile.length >= GamingConstants.ONE) {
        ValidationFactory.getImageContentValidator().validate("iconFile",
                    iconFile, threadlocalExceptions.get());
                                    ValidationFactory.getImageSizeValidator().validate("iconFile",
                    iconFile, // added size // validator

                    threadlocalExceptions.get());

        }

        if (threadlocalExceptions.get().isEmpty()) {
            try {
                final Badges badges = new Badges();
                badges.setNo_of_coins(no_of_coins);
                badges.setBadge_name(badge_name);
                badges.setScore(score);
                badges.setBadge_id(badge_id);

                final Coin coin = new Coin();
                coin.setId(badgesForm.getCoin());
                badges.setCoin(coin);

                Badges.save(badges);

                final Badges badgesObj = new Badges();
                badgesObj.setBadge_id(badges.getBadge_id());
                badgesObj.setCoin(coin);
                badgesObj.setBadge_name(badges.getBadge_name());
                badgesObj.setNo_of_coins(badges.getNo_of_coins());
                badgesObj.setScore(badges.getScore());

                if (iconFile.length >= GamingConstants.ONE) {

                    final String imgPath = "restful-services/badges/"
                            + badges.getBadge_id() + "/image";
                    badgesObj.setIconPath(imgPath);
                    final String fileName = path + badges.getBadge_id()
                            + ".png";
                    CommonUtils.writeIcon(iconFile, fileName);

                } else {
                    badgesObj.setIconPath(defaultPath);
                }

                Badges.update(badgesForm.getBadge_id(), badgesObj);

                final gamingengine.bind.Badges bindBadges = new gamingengine.bind.Badges();
                bindBadges.setBadge_id(badgesObj.getBadge_id());
                bindBadges.setCoin(badgesObj.getCoin());
                bindBadges.setNo_of_coins(badgesObj.getNo_of_coins());
                bindBadges.setBadge_name(badgesObj.getBadge_name());
                bindBadges.setIconPath(badgesObj.getIconPath());
                bindBadges.setScore(badgesObj.getScore());

                final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                final String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(bindBadges);
                return Response.ok().entity(jsonString).build();

            } catch (DBException e) {

                if (e.getMessage().startsWith(DBException.PARENT_NOT_EXISTS)) {

                    final String fieldName = e.getMessage()
                            .substring(e.getMessage().indexOf("-") + 1).trim()
                            .toLowerCase();

                    e.getValidationException()
                            .setMessage(
                                    "The "
                                            + fieldName
                                            + " is already deleted.Please refresh the page ");
                    threadlocalExceptions.get().put(fieldName,
                            e.getValidationException());

                }
            }
        }

    final Map<String, ValidationException> exceptions =                                          threadlocalExceptions.get();
    threadlocalExceptions.remove();
        

    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            final String exceptionJsonString = mapper
                    .writeValueAsString(exceptions);
            return Response.ok().entity(exceptionJsonString).build();
    
        }
```

while saving data of the form, backbone does not call the saveBadges() method of server side code

in chrome network it shows as
badges
/gamingengine/restful-services
POST
500
Internal Server Error
text/html

**now i tried as
data:this.getvalue()  in save() its sending all values to server except for iconPath**

```
**iconPath : {
                        type : "FilePicker",
                        title : "Icon"
                    }**
```

and in save() of backbone
`**var $file = $('input[name="iconPath"]', this.el);**`   this two lines are not sending iconPath, its empty any guesses

any help appreciated!!! thanks

Comment: This is more of a resteasy/jBoss question than a Backbone one. Backbone does not call methods on the server directly, it makes HTTP requests to your REST API which is written in reseasy. 500 is a generic server error. It is your server code (or lack thereof) that is responsible for throwing it, not Backbone.

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be related to the content-type expected by your service, "multipart/form-data". Backbone by default does not provide an implementation to send a multipart request on the "save" method.

Here is a link with information about how you can send the multipart-request:

[multipart form save as attributes in backbonejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20945849/multipart-form-save-as-attributes-in-backbonejs)

Also, message that you are receiving about the unexpected character ">" could be related to the "dataType" associated to the request, try to change it to "text" to avoid parsing to JSON, adding that you should be getting the correct error.

```
this.model.save(this.getValue(), {
//beforeSend : setHeader,         //added
iframe : true,
wait : true,
files : $file,
dataType: "text",
elem : this,                        
data : _.omit(this.getValue(), ['iconFile']),
silent : true..
}
```

I will suggest to review your developer console as well in Chrome, Safari or Firefox to see how the request is been sent to the server, that could give you a better understanding how your request is been received by the server.

Also, try testing your service by external "Restful" tool, chrome provided the "Advance Restful Client" where you can test your service.

Hope this information helps to solve your issue or guide you in the right direction.

Comment: badges
/gamingengine/restful-services
POST
500
Internal Server Error
text/html

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of your chrome console with the server response, Is that still the same? Have you tried sending the multipart request in the view?